# FavItems label is going out of the box

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

Hi All,

I want to put the text i.e.., FavItems inside the container/box. I tried a lot but luck. Please suggest how to put the text inside the container.

Here is the code:

.html file

```
<button uib-dropdown-toggle id="{{::favoritesDropdownPrefix}}_Button_ToggleFavoritePrescriptionsList" type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled" uib-popover="FavItems" popover-trigger="mouseenter"
          popover-animation="0" popover-placement="{{popoverPlacement || 'right'}}">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>




  .popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1010;
  display: none;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 3px !important;
  margin-top: 7px !important;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity:.90;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
.popover.top {
  margin-top: -5px !important;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
.popover.right {
  margin-left: 10px;  
}
.popover.bottom {
  margin-top: 9px !important;
  margin-left: -10px !important;
}
.popover.left {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.popover-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
h3.panel-title .popover {font-size:14px; font-weight:400; }
#Allergies_Title .popover { text-align: center; }
button .popover, .btnWrapper .popover {padding:5px; }
.widget-header .panel-title .popover {max-width:200px; }
.popover-content {
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color:#000;
}
.popover .arrow,
.popover .arrow:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
.popover .arrow {
  border-width: 11px;
}
.popover .arrow:after {
  border-width: 10px;
  content: "";
}
.popover.top .arrow {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -11px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-top-color: #999999;
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  bottom: -11px;
}
.popover.top .arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
.popover.right .arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: -11px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-color: #999999;
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.popover.right .arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  left: 1px;
  bottom: -10px;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
}
.popover.bottom .arrow {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -11px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #999999;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -11px;
}
.popover.bottom .arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  top: 1px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
.popover.left .arrow {
  top: 50%;
  right: -11px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-color: #999999;
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.popover.left .arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  right: 1px;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

There are many popovers classes used in the project.

Comment: Post your HTML please. Also, you can make a snippet to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ
Please check

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)